# How do I remove a stem cap with no visible bolt?

Tags: hybrid-bike, stem

I want to replace my bike's stem cap, but it seems to have a cover over the bolt that I can't figure out how to remove.  I've tried loosening the bolts that are underneath it, but that didn't seem to make a difference.  It's in there fairly tightly, I don't think I can lever it out without doing damage.

Any ideas?[image]

Comment: What do you expect to gain by replacing the stem cap?   An integrated gopro/computer mount would be common reasons.

Comment: That’s what I’m hoping to replace it with.

Comment: I mean the computer Mount.

Comment: What is that handlebar mount from Azur? Do you have product link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely a large bolt that runs down the center of your steerer tube and interfaces with a star nut or similar.  This is required to set the preload on your headset bearings.

I am unfamiliar with this exact top-cap but there must be a way to access that bolt.   If you examine your replacement stem cap, it should be a metal disk with a hole in the middle for the bolt.

I **suspect** the black disk with the FDKOBE wording is a clip-on cap, either clipped around the edge or perhaps in the middle.   That bulge in the middle will be where the bolt's head is, probably a 6mm hex though other sizes may be used.

Try and lever it off around the outside seam.

Comment: Is the central bolt cover plastic? You’ll be able to tell by tapping it with a screwdriver and listening. If plastic then use a blade to get under the edge and lever it out as it’s just a friction fit. Once you extract it by a small amount you can use blunter tools to finish. You might visually damage the cover or even break it but it’s only a cosmetic feature.

Comment: It’s not plastic, definitely metal. I tried using a blade to lever it out, but I couldn’t get anything wedged in there. It’s very tightly in there.

Comment: @Nimmy Criggie has to be correct that there should be a bolt to set the preload. Had you tried rotating your top cap by hand? Little torque is required for preload. If the top cap has a bolt built in, I wonder if you could just rotate it off. Now, why would someone design a top cap + integrated bolt without a hex or torx broach to rotate it, I don't know; here's an example of what I'm thinking of https://www.omniracer.com/product-page/race-lite-alloy-stem-headset-top-cap-bolt

Comment: Ah, I see. I haven’t tried that. Not sure how I would get a grip on the lip given it’s so thin. Imll take another look in the morning.

Comment: I got it! Had to remove all the bolts along the stem, which loosened the original top cap enough that it would spin and I could jiggle it a bit, which I turn loosened the rubber cap that was very firmly stopped in the centre, and I could finally access the bolt! Thanks for the help and advice, my little bike computer now has a home ☺️

Comment: @Nimmy maybe too late but can you add a photo of the detached top cap / rubber thing for a future visitor